# Copying a vector from the stack onto the heap

Tags: c++, heap-memory, stack-memory

I have method that takes in a const vector reference. I want to put a mutable version of the vector on the heap and return that

This compiles but I am unsure if it is actually doing what I think. I am not sure if I am getting lucky with the memory here:

```
vector<Type> *vect = new vector<Type>;
*vect = vectReference;
```

Comment: The big question here is: Why do you want to put a new vector on the heap? If you don't understand how to do that, you probably don't want to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's OK, you made dynamically allocated `vector` copy. But the same could be done in more short way using copy constructor instead of default constructor and assignment operator:

```
vector<Type> *vect = new vector<Type>(vectReference);
```

Also would like to suggest to use smart pointer instead of raw one: `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` - depending on your code semantics.

Comment: I would suggest not using a pointer at all.  There's almost never any reason to dynamically allocate an `std::vector`.

Comment: @JamesKanze E.g. `vector` object shared between several instances of another object.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you, you do it right. On second line you copy vector from vectReference into vect allocated on heap.

Answer (score 1):

This code works correctly.

However, you need to ensure that the "vect" allocates space, which should be freed later, so you probably want to use a std::auto_ptr to ensure, that the object is being destroyed:

```
std::auto_ptr<std::vector<Type> > vect(new std::vector<Type>);
*vect = vectReference;
```

Answer (score 1):

This will perform exactly what you want. you can even shorten it by:

```
vector<Type> *vect = new vector<Type>(vectReference);
```

to invoke the copy constructor rather than the assignment operator.